# select option values are not displaying through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

```
$.each(data.aaData, function(i, obj) {
    var opt_data = "<option value=" + obj.value + ">" + obj.text + "</option>";
    $(opt_data).appendTo('#reqtype'); 
}); 

alert($('#reqtype :selected').text());
var numberOfOptions = $('select#reqtype option').length
alert(numberOfOptions);
```

After appending the option values to 'reqtype' selectcombobox through jquery, i tried to alert the number of option values and selectedvalue. Its showing the correct number. But in select combobox is not listing the values.still its empty. 
I tried with different jqueries, its values are showing properly through jquery. But its not displaying the select options in HTML view.select combobox is empty only.

Comment: Your code should work fine - see https://jsfiddle.net/vzkkt9m2/. Are you sure that you have only one element with an `id` of `reqtype` in the page?

Comment: yes i checked the code, only one element with an id of reqtype in the page

Comment: Sorry, I'm unable to help you then as what you've shown works fine - as can be seen in the above example

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you should try:

```
var opt_data = '';
$.each(data.aaData, function(i, obj) {
    opt_data += "<option value=" + obj.value + ">" + obj.text + "</option>";
}); 
$('#reqtype').html(opt_data);
alert($('#reqtype :selected').text());
```